# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable Where is int?

Tags: python, django, excel

I got an error,`TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable` .
I wanna connect 2 excel data 
[image: excel1]

[image: excel2]
to User model.

So my ideal output is

```
1|1|Blear|40|false|l|America|A|1
2|5|Tom|23|true|o|UK|A|3
3|9|Rose|52|false|m
4|10|Karen||||Singapore|C|2
```

For example,Rose data of user_id＝3 is not in second excel, in that case being 2nd data empty is ok.I am thinking putting 2nd excel in dictionary type to User model.

I searched the errors I thought this part `for data in data_dict` was wrong, I changed it  into `for data in range(len(data_dict))` but same error happens.I really cannot understand where is wrong.How should I fix this?

Now views.py is

```
#coding:utf-8
from django.shortcuts import render
import xlrd
from .models import User

book = xlrd.open_workbook('../data/excel1.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(1)

def build_employee(employee):
  if employee == 'leader':
     return 'l'
  if employee == 'manager':
     return 'm'
  if employee == 'others':
     return 'o'

for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):
  rows = sheet.row_values(row_index) 
  is_man = rows[4] != ""
  emp = build_employee(rows[5])
  user = User(user_id=rows[1], name_id=rows[2], name=rows[3], 
              age=rows[4],man=is_man,employee=emp)
  user.save()

book2 = xlrd.open_workbook('../data/excel2.xlsx')
sheet2 = book2.sheet_by_index(0)
headers = sheet2.row_values(0)

large_item = None
data_dict = {}
for row_index in range(sheet2.nrows):
    rows2 = sheet2.row_values(row_index)
    large_item = rows2[1] or large_item

    # Create dict with headers and row values
    row_data = {}
    for idx_col, value in enumerate(rows2):
        header_value = headers[idx_col]
        # Avoid to add empty column. A column in your example
        if header_value:
            row_data[headers[idx_col]] = value
            # Add row_data to your data_dict with
    data_dict[row_index] = row_data
    for row_number, row_data in data_dict.items():
        user1 = User.objects.filter(user_id = data['user_id']).exists()
        if user1:
            user1.__dict__.update(**data_dict)
            user1.save()
```

Now Traceback is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/XXX/testapp/app/views.py", line 123, in <module>
    user1 = User.objects.filter(user_id = row_data['user_id']).exists()
KeyError: 'user_id'
```

Comment: What's the stacktrace of this error?

Comment: Post the full stacktrace

Comment: @birryree I added traceback, if u know something, please help me.

Comment: @Exprator I added traceback, if u know something, please help me.

Comment: i think you are not skipping the header. `data['user_id']` is trying to convert int('user_id') because `user_id` is int in db.

Comment: @user8563636 just add a print(data['user_id']) and print(type(data['user_id')) after this line for data in data_dict: and show what it prints in the console

Comment: @VikashSingh you are maybe right.Excel's header is 1~5 row, but I only skipped 1 rows.But I cannot understand how to skip 1~5 row as header.How should I write it?

Comment: @Exprator I printed out print(data['user_id']) and print(type(data['user_id')) ,both of them were told TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable.

Comment: Of course, see my answer for the reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` is an integer. So calling data like a dict raises that expection.

```
>>> a=1
>>> a['a']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Why is it an int ? Because you're iterating over `data`'s keys:

```
>>> a={1: 'x', 2: 'c'}
>>> for i in a: print(i)
... 
1
2
```

Try using `items()` as such:

```
>>> for key, value in a.items(): print(key, value)
... 
1 x
2 c
```

Or, in your specific case:

```
for row_number, row_data in data_dict.items():
    print(row_number, row_data)
```

See [looping techniques for dict documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) for details.

Comment: should' he/she get a key error at `data['user_id']` in that case ??

Comment: KeyError is when data is a dict but the key was not found in it.

Comment: that makes sense.

Comment: @jpic thx ur answers.I wrote ur code, but new error happens.I updated my question(views.py & models.py)Did I misunderstand ur answers?If u know something, please help me.